# Processing a Django form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a problem using Django forms while learning Django and adapting code from a variety of online courses and examples. As a result, the code may be “messy” – but if I can get it to work the way I need, I can improve my coding style later.

I wish to display a template that contains a form. Some of the data displayed in the page rendered in the template is read from one table/model, polls_CC_Questions, and I wish to write data input in the page into a related table, polls_CC_Resp_NoFK.

The models used are:

```
class CC_Questions(models.Model):
    q_text = models.CharField('Question text', max_length=200)
    C1_Type = models.CharField('Choice 1 Type', max_length=2)
    Choice1_text = models.CharField('Choice 1 text', max_length=100)
    C2_Type = models.CharField('Choice 2 Type', max_length=2)
    Choice2_text = models.CharField('Choice 2 text', max_length=100)
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return self.q_text[:20]


class CC_Resp_NoFK(models.Model):
    Person_ID = models.IntegerField()
    Test_date = models.DateTimeField('date test taken')
    Q_ID = models.IntegerField()
    Response_value = models.IntegerField(default=0,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(-100)])
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Person_ID
```

Now I can display the template containing valid data when I enter the url:
http://localhost:8000/polls/p2vote/4/
This is processed in urls.py

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
…..
……
    # ex: /polls/p2vote/<q_id>
    path('p2vote/<int:q_id>/', p2_views.p2vote, name='p2vote'),
…..
```

The views.py entry that is used:

```
def p2vote(request,q_id): 
    #next line has been copied from CC_quest view to GET Question data
    CC_question = get_object_or_404(CC_Questions, pk=q_id)
    #
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/polls/p2')
    else:
        formV = VoteForm()
    #context = {'form' : formV}
    return render(request, 'pollapp2/vote.html', {'var_name':CC_question,'form' : VoteForm()})
```

in forms.py

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CC_Resp_NoFK
        fields = ['Person_ID', 'Test_date', 'Q_ID','Response_value']
```

The template launched, uses data from the polls_CC_Questions model/table to create the labels of the input field. This works fine so my displayed page
http://localhost:8000/polls/p2vote/5/
Displays data from the CC_Questions table, “carried in the variable varname” what the questions and their choices are. For example, the template displays the contents of {{ var_name.q_text }} and {{ var_name.Choice1_text }} , see below

Also, the page displayed containing the ModelForm is correctly displayed with labels. The template used :

```
<!-- vote.html based on create.html -->
<!-- 2022-02-17 
Change text on page
Extracted data from CC_Question record passed as varname
-->

{% extends "pollapp2/base.html" %}
<!-- load widget tools to give me more control over layout of form in template -->
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<!-- block Title is the name in the tab -->
{% block title %}Vote on Question{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Select one from two choices</h3>
            </div>

            <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="question">Question to answer</label>
                {{ var_name.q_text }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Choice1_text ">Choice 1</label>

            {{ var_name.Choice1_text }}


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="option2">Choice 2</label>

            {{ var_name.Choice2_text }}

                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
<!-- Attempt at Input fields follow -->
        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Person_id">Person ID</label>
    {% render_field form.Person_ID rows="1" class="form-control" %}<br>
                <label for="Test_date">Test Date</label>
    {% render_field form.Test_date rows="1" class="form-control" %}<br>
         <label for="Q_ID">Question ID</label>
    {% render_field form.Q_ID rows="1" class="form-control" %}  <br>
                <label for="Response_value">Response value</label>
    {% render_field form.Response_value rows="1" class="form-control" %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <hr />
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

To summarise. All the above “works” in the sense a page is displayed when url : http://localhost:8000/polls/p2vote/X/ is entered in the browser and “X” is the id of the question , extracting data from the model: CC_questions. Also, on the page are input boxes created by the form, VoteForm, that allow data to be entered into table/model CC_Resp_noFK.
However, what I want to do is NOT offer Q_ID as an input field in the page, but instead populate it with the value from variable {{ var_name.id }}. I can’t work out whether I need to modify the vote.html template in some way, particularly the line:

```
<label for="Q_ID">Question ID</label>
    {% render_field form.Q_ID rows="1" class="form-control" %}   << change this ??
```

or the view, somewhere around form.save() ??

```
def p2vote(request,q_id): 
    #next line has been copied from CC_quest view to get Question data
    CC_question = get_object_or_404(CC_Questions, pk=q_id)
    #
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  << Somewhere around here ??
            return redirect('/polls/p2') 
    else:
        formV = VoteForm()
        #context = {'form' : formV}
        # return render(request, 'pollapp2/vote.html', context)
        # following return tries to send question record into vote.html template
    return render(request, 'pollapp2/vote.html', {'var_name':CC_question,'form' : VoteForm()})
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: When I did use a foreign key in the original version of the responses model.  I got a variety of errors when the Vote template/form/view tried to write to the CC_Responses table (Original version of model that included a foreign key) like "Q_ID_id" not found - so I guessed that Django was sticking an "_id" on the end of the field name - which it was . I built a new model CC_Resp_NoFK and that got round that problem - maybe not "pretty" or "good" but at least I could proceed and write some data to the responses model.

Comment: Also, in a previous iteration of the template (I think it was the template), the "input box" was being prepopulated with values of the Question text - my code was somehow using the foreign key in CC_Responses to select the record from the CC_Questions model/table and displaying the Question text as selectable options. I fixed that, somehow, and tried to forget about that bit of code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think I forgot to tag you on my previous comments, responding to your comment.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Once the current is issue is fixed I will revert to the previous version of the model with the foreign key and try to reproduce the problem with Q_ID-id - then create a new question - so hopefully someone can explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Delete Q_ID from VoteForm.

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CC_Resp_NoFK
        fields = ['Person_ID', 'Test_date', 'Response_value']
```

Step 2: Add Q_ID after check if the form is valid and before save the object.

```
def p2vote(request,q_id): 
    #next line has been copied from CC_quest view to get Question data
    CC_question = get_object_or_404(CC_Questions, pk=q_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save(commit=False)
            item.Q_ID = q_id
            item.save()
            return redirect('/polls/p2')
```

Comment: I made your suggested addition to the p2Vote view. The template still displayed Question ID as an input box, which makes sense as I didn't change the template. When I populated the fields in the Vote screen I got the following Django error                Exception Value: 'VoteForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: You are right. cleaned_data has no sense before is_valid function. I am editing my answer

Comment: That's it. Fixed ! Just so I understand what's going. What follows is  naive understanding of the operation of the modified p2Vote view. item = form.save(commit=False) places all the values entered in the form into variable "item". Then item.Q_ID = q_id takes the value of quesiton-id read from the CC_Questions model and places that value "into" Q_ID to be written to CC_Resp_NoFK. Finally item.save() writes the data as a new record to the CC_Resp_NoFK model. Is that it? Is this kind of program "standard" , and I should learn it, or a "fix" to get round issues in my code?

Comment: Exactly, you are right. commit=False is used to not saving the object, because the Q_ID field is non nullable and if you try to save it before assigning it, it would give an error. About your code, you should try to use ForeignKey field. And I suggest you to use Class based views that are perfect to solve this kind of problems